# Playing music in python in replit

Tags: python, audio, replit

I'm having trouble playing music in the background of my program in replit. I have tried using Pygame but couldn't get that to work, so I followed the [official replit tutorial video](https://youtu.be/CuIV2-ivg0U).

I get the confirm audio screen but nothing plays, my file is `.wav` and is 29 secs long and plays when I go directly onto the file, but not when the program runs. I have uploaded the file into replit so it appears alongside `main.py`.

Any help would be appreciated, let me know if any additional info is needed

My code:

```
from replit import audio
source = audio.play_file("music.wav")
while True:
  pass
```

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason, replit doesn't actually let you run code alongside the playing of music. Get rid of

```
while True:
    pass
```

It should work then

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](https://docs.replit.com/tutorials/audio), Replit has trouble using

```
    while True:
       pass
```

If you want to do nothing while the audio file is running, instead use `time.sleep`. You should also be able to run code while the file is running with no problems.